# Error #1064, with Select column,* from table

Tags: mysql

Okay, just was debugging something and I found a wired error, probably it should be documented somewhere, but I search MYSQL documentation and didn't found anything. Here is the sql query, that produce `1064` error near `* from table`,

```
Select char_length(zip), zip, *  from tbllocations
```

But this below one works fine:

```
Select *, char_length(zip), zip from tbllocations
```

Cannot we use `*` at end of column list? I test this query on MySQL 5.5.41 and MySql 5.0.95. I didn't notice this error before. I rewrite query to avoid special/hidden characters.

Aren't they same query except change in order of columns? Any explanation or resource to look for one.

EDIT:

Just run `Select  char_length(zip), zip, tbllocations.* from tbllocations` and it works fine? So looks like I am hitting some bug? or anything logical, I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> - A select list consisting only of a single unqualified * can be used as shorthand to select all columns from all tables:
> - `SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ... tbl_name.*` can be used as a qualified shorthand to select all columns from the named table:
> - `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ...` Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To
>     avoid this problem, use a qualified tbl_name.* reference
>
>   `SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...`

Comment: I did miss that line in documentation, but still surprise that order of column did error. Since it is documented, we have to live with that :).Thanks for information.

Comment: You're welcome. I also believe the SQL standard doesn't allow anything else but * if used, so MySQL is a little more flexible here.